# Application Insights get most recent exception for each grouped by custom property

Tags: azure-application-insights

Our exceptions have a custom field: customDimensions.ActivityId

```
exceptions | where isnotnull(customDimensions.ActivityId) |  extend actid = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId) | distinct actid
```

I'd like to get the most recent exception for each activity id.

Good answer below, I ended up going with:

```
exceptions
| extend actid = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| where isnotnull(actid)
| summarize arg_min(timestamp, *) by actid
| order by timestamp desc
```

Because I actually want the first message with an exception to occur during an activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this doc](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Aggregation-functions/arg_max()) about arg_max() aggregation, this should be as easy as

```
exceptions
| where isnotnull(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| extend actid = tostring(customDimensions.ActivityId)
| summarize arg_max(timestamp, *) by actid
```